# Add a SVG image as an icon in Button (react-bootstrap)?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I want to get the result like shown in the image below. I'm using `Button` from [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/).

```
<Button size="lg" className={`${styles.premium} w-100 mt-5 mb-3`}>
  Abonnement Premium
</Button>
```

How can i add a `SVG` image to a Button as an icon in React?

[image: Result desired]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import the image
`import yourImg from '../to/your/image.svg';`

Just add it in front of the words

```
<Button size="lg" className={`${styles.premium} w-100 mt-5 mb-3`}>
  <img src={yourImg} /> Abonnement Premium
</Button>
```